# No architectures to compile for error when trying to set up unit testing in existing project

Tags: ios, unit-testing

I am currently working on an existing iOS project in Xcode 4, and I wanted to add unit-testing using Xcode's built-in unit testing framework (OCUnit).

I followed this guide http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/developertools/Conceptual/UnitTesting/02-Setting_Up_Unit_Tests_in_a_Project/setting_up.html on setting up unit testing, but when I try to run the tests, I get the following error:
No architectures to compile for (ARCHS=x86_64, VALID_ARCHS=armv7 armv7s).

I really don't want to migrate everything to a new project, because this project is a very large and unweildy one. However, I really do want to add unit testing.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: For your test target -> Build Settings -> Architectures, it should be i386 for Simulator and armv7 for iOS sdk. Can you check and confirm?

Comment: I messed around with the architectures setting quite a lot but it did not help. What I had to do was edit the *valid architectures* setting to $(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_64_BIT). For whatever reason, it was not set automatically.

Answer (score 0):

After trying to add unit tests several times over, I discovered that in the page for my test target, under build settings -> architectures, there is an entry named *valid architectures*. I tried messing with the architectures setting, and that did not work, but changing the *valid architectures* for the unit test target to

> $(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_64_BIT)

made it compile!

I still have to deal adding missing frameworks in the test target, but this approach answers my main question.